# How to select an item ( maybe item row ) in a listview in vb6?

Tags: listview, vb6

How do I select an item (maybe item row) in a listview in vb6?
I mean, is there any code to do something like programmatically clicking an item at runtime?

somebody told me this :

```
listview.ListItems(1).Selected = True
listview.select()
```

but it is not working!

Answer (score 6):

Simply set the `.SelectedItem` property:

```
Set ListView.SelectedItem = ListView.ListItems(3)
```

Also be careful as the listview can have separate "selected" and "highlighted" items.
`.SelectedItem` sets the highlighted item and selects it at the same time. `Item.Selected` just selectes it, but when reading them back they may be different.

Answer (score 2):

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    ListView1.MultiSelect = True
    For a = 1 To 10
    Randomize Time
    ListView1.ListItems.Item(a).Selected = True
    Next
    ListView1.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    For a = 1 To 20
    ListView1.ListItems.Add , , a
    Next
End Sub
```

Do not forget to set `HideSelection` property to `False`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView1_ItemClick ListView1.ListItems.item(1)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!